# Highcharts and highstock license with google ads web site

Tags: highcharts

if i use `highcharts` or `highstock` in my web site and add some `Google Ads` to this web site does my web site consider as a profit site and requires me to buy a license

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you would have to buy a license.  The below is directly from their website:

**What is a commercial website?**

A commercial website is a website which purpose is **generating revenue or cash flow of any type**, and that isn't under a non-profit organization. So if you're selling a product, selling advertisement, selling a service or just marketing a commercial business, your site is commercial. A company website is also commercial even if it doesn't sell anything, as it's purpose is to front a commercial company.

So, according to the above if `Google Ads` generates any profit then you are required to purchase a license.